# pr2_nav_tutorial.launch is not a launch file name

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i run the
"PR2 Simulator Workshop"
and in section
8.PR2 Navigation Stack Demo
I create a launch script for starting all necessary navigation components, and save it as ~/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch in my home directory (user@ubuntu).
When i run:
roslaunch ~/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch
I take:
/home/user/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch] is not a launch file name.
Also, i have not the pr2_nav_tutorial package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230164/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch-is-not-a-launch-file-name./) by [G strat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26332/g-strat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the solution is
roslaunch pr2_nav_tutorial.launch and no
roslaunch ~/pr2_nav_tutorial.launch

---

Originally posted by [G strat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26332/g-strat/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0